# Converting number to date in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, datetime

I have a numeric field in my Oracle database that represents the number of days since Dec 28, 1800. However I am trying to select it (for another application) as the current date it represents. I'm not too familiar with Oracle commands (I'm used to SQL), so I was wondering if anyone could provide some assistance. Thanks.

ex: 77650 = Saturday, August 3, 2013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, get this out of the way, your life would be easier if you stored dates in a date data-type.

However, to answer your question to add days to a date in Oracle you can use the `+` operator.

Firstly though you have to have a date so I'll convert the 28th December 1800 into a date using to inbuilt [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function then add the number. In your case you would want:

```
select to_date('1800/12/28','yyyy/mm/dd') + 77650 from dual
```

I've set up a [little SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2a09/1) to demonstrate for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! If it were up to me, I would have most certainly done it right the first time. However it is a read-only db that I had no part in creating. Thanks again for your help, that worked perfectly.