# ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am doing a simple **Oracle INSERT** and I keep getting this error:
`[Err] ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

```
INSERT INTO MY.LOGFILE
(id,severity,category,logdate,appendername,message,extrainfo)
VALUES
(
"dee205e29ec34",
"FATAL",
"facade.uploader.model",
"2013-06-11 17:16:31",
"LOGDB",
NULL,
NULL
)
```

Comment: Use single quotes (apostrophes) around string literals e.g. 'FATAL'.  Double quotes are optionally (rarely) used around identifiers like column names.

Comment: if you're using variables in PL/SQL, it can also mean you haven't defined the variable
e.g. 
declare
  v_my_var number := 1;
INSERT INTO tbl (col_name) values (my_var); -- note mispelled variable name

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Replace double quotes with single ones:

```
INSERT
INTO    MY.LOGFILE
        (id,severity,category,logdate,appendername,message,extrainfo)
VALUES  (
       'dee205e29ec34',
       'FATAL',
       'facade.uploader.model',
       '2013-06-11 17:16:31',
       'LOGDB',
       NULL,
       NULL
       )
```

In SQL, double quotes are used to mark identifiers, not string constants.

Comment: This is the error I am getting now.
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: @GeorgeMurphy: please post your table definition.

Comment: That's almost definitely because `logdate` is a _date_ @George, you're trying to insert a _character_. You need to convert it to a date using [TO_DATE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132), see something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883923/converting-number-to-date-in-oracle/11884028#11884028 or hundreds of others...

Comment: It is work fine when replace double quotes with single ones