# insert value into linked server (ODBC)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, odbc

I have a sql server that connect to an oracle db via ODBC.

On the sql box I run a query to pull data using:

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM dbName.tableName') AT [LinkedServer];
```

This returns the full table with column names etc

I am now trying to update the table with values using:

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO dbName.tableName (VALUE_ID, VALUE_NAME, VALUE_SITE, ACTIVE) VALUES ("18", "TEST", "3", "Y")') AT [LinkedServer];
```

With this I get the following:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServer" returned
>   message "[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00984: column not allowed here".

With selecting all from the table I can confirm that it exists and values exist under those column names.

I have read that this issue may be caused by using a column name as a value but this is nit teh case here.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is MySQL involved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00984: column not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054221/ora-00984-column-not-allowed-here)

Comment: I think your double quotation is the issue

Comment: You are correct, becasue the EXEC was wrapped in single quotations I incorrectly wrapped the value in double quotes. I tested with 2 single quotes and  this resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, becasue the EXEC was wrapped in single quotations I incorrectly wrapped the value in double quotes. I tested with 2 single quotes and this resolved issue.